# Why Php is escaping when using single quotes?

Tags: php, latex

why php escapes backslashes when using single quotes?

I'm trying to output `\\` on a LaTex math code but the following code is outputting
`\`  instead of `\\` even when using single quotes.
Is there anyway to do this instead of echoing `\\\\`? like any configuration file?

```
<?php
echo '\\';
?>
```

Comment: is ur expected output dblquot\dblquot ???

Comment: My expected output was two backslashes, I managed to get it using nowdoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference between single or double quotes is only about parsing variables or not.

I'm really not sure if you can do what you want, it's like asking if $ character could not be used as variable prefix in doubles quotes...

Maybe you should look at heredoc and nowdoc in http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

Each backslash must be escaped:

```
echo '\\\\';
```